# top right is not working on byRoundingcorners in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

im trying to make rounded corners for the sub view in the top left and top right using the following code

```
 maskLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: view.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.topRight, .topLeft], cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).cgPath
```

also tried in viewDidLayoutSubviews(), but only left border radius is working... the right border radius is not working.

can someone help me out

Answer (score 4):

You may miss configure something , here `maskedCorners` rounds top left && right --- and `roundCorners` rounds bottom left && right

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let redBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 128, height: 128))
    let blueBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 128, height: 128))
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        redBox.backgroundColor = .red
        redBox.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        redBox.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
        view.addSubview(redBox)

        blueBox.backgroundColor = .blue
        view.addSubview(blueBox)
    }


    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        blueBox.roundCorners(corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight], radius: 25.0)
    }

}

extension UIView {
    func roundCorners(corners: UIRectCorner, radius: CGFloat) {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        let mask = CAShapeLayer()
        mask.path = path.cgPath
        layer.mask = mask
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: any chance of getting without specigying the location, height, width of the view?   
    let redBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 128, height: 128))
    let blueBox = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 300, width: 128, height: 128))

Answer (score 1):

That often happens when your `maskLayer` is wider than the view it masks.

See the diagram below. Overlapped area is a rectangle with one corner rounded.

[image: e]

Comment: yes i understand. how can i overcome this.....I want to execute the code after the subview is completely loaded

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

yourView.roundCorners(topLeft: 25, topRight: 25)
bookImage.clipsToBounds = true


}
```